# if there is duplicate values from an array delete all duplicates values

Tags: php, arrays

My problem is I had two array that i merged together to make one, but when i merged them i saw there was duplicates values.

Anyone knows if there are duplicate values "delete" every values who contains the same value like :

```
$a=array("red", "green", "red", "blue");
```

Instead of this result with array_unique :

```
[0] => red
[1] => green
[3] => blue
```

have this result :

```
[1] => green
[3] => blue
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$a=array("red", "green", "red", "blue", "blue", "yellow");
$duplicates = [];
for ($i=0; $i<count($a)-1; $i++) {
    for($j=$i+1; $j<count($a); $j++) {
        if ($a[$i] === $a[$j]) {
            $duplicates[] = $i;
            $duplicates[] = $j;
        }
    }
}

foreach($duplicates as $index) {
    unset($a[$index]);
}

print_r($a);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [1] => green
    [5] => yellow
)
```